# deploy a jee6 web application in glassfish v3.1.1

Tags: java-ee-6, glassfish-3

What things have to taken care for deploy a web appl ( war ) in glassfish v3.1.1 ( glassfish-3.1.1-web-windows.exe installer ) , the appl. is developed using netbeans 7.0.1. I am using postgresql database . Developement machine and Production machine is different and is not connected to each other. Any detailed step by step instruction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what resources your application would need to run successfully on the application server.

e.g. If your application uses container managed persistence then you have to make sure that you create the required JDBC connection pool and resource on the server before you can deploy your application server. If you check the persistence.xml file you will see if your application uses some jta-datasource (the value provided there is actually the JNDI name of the JDBC resource created on the server). Here you might also have to supply the required JDBC driver to the server if it is not package within the application.

What you can do is install the same application server on your local machine and deploy the application there and see if it fails. If it fails then you can check the stacktrace to find out the reason for failure.